# Wordpress installed on my site, but all other files/folders I put in the directory do not show up

Tags: wordpress

Updated Explanation:

I am getting 404 errors for every picture or file I put in the directory via FTP. Here is an example:  (The test.html file includes "hello", I've tried html code, css files, images).

[image: Example 1]

The Reason why this is a huge issue is because I am trying to do custom templates for my wordpress site but when I load the .php files (of my templates) on to the server they don't show up in wordpress. Please help me. This problem is impossible to google for/explain well.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.net$
```

This is probably related to your problem. Your site isn't website.net.

I'm not exactly sure what WordPress has to do with anything since you are not using it for the static html file.

Comment: I have created a google maps app that I want to put on this server and it's location would be soemthing like WWW.lindsaymantzel.com/googlemap/index.html but I cannot get it to work because wordpress is overwriting something and gives 404 even though /lindsay/test.html exists